# Finding a bug in Creation of expression tree

Tags: c, expression-trees

I am trying to create expression tree but I am not getting a relevent output. In this code I tried many times to check the mistakes in my code but I can't find one. Please someone help me solve the bug in this program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct tree
{
    char a;
    struct tree *llink;
    struct tree *rlink;
} *stack[20];

int top=0;

void push(struct tree* root)
{
    stack[top]=root;
    top++;
}

struct tree* pop()
{
    return stack[top--];
}

void inorderdisplay(struct tree *temp)
{
    if (temp!=NULL) {
        inorderdisplay(temp->llink);
        printf("%c ",temp->a);
        inorderdisplay(temp->rlink);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct tree *root;
    char exp[100];

    scanf("%s",exp);

    for (i=0; exp[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        root=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
        root->a=exp[i];
        root->llink=NULL;
        root->rlink=NULL;

        if( exp[i]>=65 && exp[i]<=90);
        else {
            root->llink=pop();
            root->rlink=pop();
        }
        push(root);
    }
    inorderdisplay(stack[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to indent your code, and add some empty lines to create paragraphs. It will make the code much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) might also be very useful. Especially since your `pop` function will not actually "pop" the last node in the stack.

Comment: Lastly, don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you by e.g. `65` means the ASCII encoded value for `'A'` then explicitly use `'A'` instead. Or even better, use [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: What is the input you have given, what is the expected output and what is the actual output you are getting?

Comment: `stack[top++]` pairs with `stack[--top]`.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje my input is "AB-" expected output is "B-A" ouput I am getting is "- B" (there is a space between minus and B )

Answer (score 1):

I should replace return statement in pop function to

```
return stack[--top];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you push a node, it becomes the new root. Connecting left tree and right tree is required.

```
struct tree* push(struct tree* node, struct tree* root,
                                int join_left)
{
   if(join_left)
     node->llink=root;
  else
    node->rlink=root;

  return node;
}
```

In main

```
int main(void)
{
  struct tree *root=NULL;

   ....
  node = malloc(sizeof struct tree);
  node->llink=NULL;
  node->rlink=NULL;

     ...
     root = push(node, root, 1);

    ....
}
```